# Any reason for specifying -type f in find when looking for files with SUID bit set?

Tags: suid

What's the reason for using `-type f` with `find / -perm -u=s -type f 2>/dev/null`. I see this all over the Internet and don't understand  why to specify the type as regular file if look for SUID bit set. SUID can be set only of files and not directories so why `-type f`  ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Why do you say suid can be set only on files? You can set them on directories just fine, they won't take effect on Linux.

Comment: @muru ok, let me explain further. I was reading about privilege escalation techniques under Linux and one of them mentioned the SUID bit. So as you say, yes, the SUID bit can be set on a directory but AFAIK it has no effect. How could that be exploited? ah ok, I got it, because it has not effect od directories we do not care about them hence the file switch .

Answer (score 2):

The setuid bit *can* be set on directories, even though it typically doesn’t have any effect.

(On some BSDs it can have the same effect as setgid, setting the owner of newly-created files.)